# Import json data into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, parsing, json

I have a text file in json format and want to read it into Excel.  A very simplified example of the json file has the following structure:

```
{ [
  { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 },
  { 'a': 20, 'b': 22 },
  { 'a': 11, 'b': 24 }
] }
```

I want to convert it to Excel in which each record becomes a row in excel with the selected parameters as the column headers.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance; which of the values above are the "records" and which are the "selected parameters"?

Comment: A record would be { 'a': 10, 'b': 20 } and the parameters would be 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: This may get a better response on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in VBA with the `vba-json` [library](http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/).  Here's an example of some code I [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5773683/13295):

```
Sub TestJsonDecode() 'This works, uses vba-json library 
    Dim lib As New JSONLib 'Instantiate JSON class object 
    Dim jsonParsedObj As Object 'Not needed 

    jsonString = "{'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}" 
    Set jsonParsedObj = lib.parse(CStr(jsonString)) 

    For Each keyName In jsonParsedObj.keys 
        MsgBox "Keyname=" & keyName & "//Value=" & jsonParsedObj(keyName) 
    Next 

    Set jsonParsedObj = Nothing 
    Set lib = Nothing 
End Sub 

Sub TestJsonEncode() 'This works, uses vba-json library 
    Dim lib As New JSONLib 'Instantiate JSON class object 
    Set arr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 

    arr("key1") = "val1" 
    arr("key2") = "val2" 

    MsgBox lib.toString(arr) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a great answer any more without google code being around to download this

Answer (score 1):

Here are some example excel downloads with json excel connversion capabilities. You can do it straight from within excel.

(Page no longer available:) http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json

You may be able to use the last version archived on the Wayback Machine at
https://web.archive.org/web/20200217050634/http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json

Answer (score 1):

1. Paste the JSON into [json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com).
2. Download the resultant CSV file.
3. Open the CSV file up in Excel.